# python - using __init__.py for modules in multiple dirs

Tags: python, module

I'm having a hard time understanding this.

Lets assume I have a directory tree that looks like this:

~/speech
-- `__init__.py`
-- program.py
`----------------`
~/speech/parts
----`__init__.py`
----noun.py
----verb.py
`----------------`
~/speech/sentence
----`__init__.py`
----subject.py
----predicate.py

the `__init__.py` files are blank. I created them by issuing $ touch `__init__.py`
when i try to import anything, I get NameError: 'whatever' not defined.
I've tried the whatever as both the directory name, and the individual file names.

every other problem i've had in python has been because I'm over-thinking things and trying to make it more complicated than it really is. ( curse the c++ habits! )

Comment: search SO for sys.path or PYTHONPATH...often discussed

Comment: Can you qualify what you mean by "import anything"?

Comment: When I read the tidbit from the python site that discusses the module search path, I get the feeling that it looks in ~/speech, ~/speech/parts, etc.  When i say "import anything" i meant to convey that i can not import anything that's not in either /usr/local/lib/python or the dir where I issued python ./program.py   When i'm creating a new program, where else should I be putting it other than in ~/someDirNameForPython? It doesn't make since (nor is it proper) to put it directly in the lib's while in devel

Answer (score 1):

Unless `~` is your current directory or is in `sys.path` (which it shouldn't be) you won't be able to use any packages contained in it, including `speech` and its subpackages. Put the directory structure somewhere sane and add that path to `$PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

you can quickly add your current directory to the python search path with:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)
```

Here's some background information you should read:

[Python's Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i finally figured it out.

If I want it to look like "java-style classes", then I import via:

```
import parts.noun  
import sentence.subject  
parts.noun.defineNouns()  
sentence.subject.thePersonOrThing()
```

If I want it to look more like C/++ style lib call, then I import via:

```
from parts.noun import defineNouns  
from sentence.subject import thePersonOrThing  
defineNouns()  
thePersonOrThing()
```

`*sigh*` it's so simple, it's hard.